# itmzファイルをWindowsで開きたい

Tags: windows

**実現したいこと**
・itmzファイルをPC（Windows）で開きたいです。

**状況**
調べたところ、itmzファイルに対応している（itmzを開けるアプリがある）のはiOSのみという情報があり、Windowsで開く方法が見当たりませんでした。

**具体的な質問**
Windowsでitmzファイルを開けるフリーソフト、または開く方法はありますでしょうか？
お手数ですが、具体的なソフト名や開く手順を教えていただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

マインドマップツールの iThoughts 用のファイルであるなら、[Windows 版](https://www.toketaware.com/ithoughts-win) も存在するようです。
(基本的には有償ツールのようですが、無料の試用版も用意されている模様)

該当ファイルをどのように入手したのか分かりませんが、他のマインドマップツール向けのファイル形式と [エクスポート/インポートも可能](https://www.toketaware.com/ithoughts-faq-compatibility) なようなので、iOS 版が使える環境で Freemind 向け等の形式でエクスポートしてもらうのも一つの方法可と思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！試してみます。